# Error al enviar petición a un web service vía SOAP en PHP

Tags: php, xml, webservice, soap, wsdl

Este es mi código php para llamar a la función del web service:

```
require_once 'nuSoap/nusoap.php';

$client = new nusoap_client('https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co/habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica/facturaElectronica.wsdl',true);

$username = 'xxxxx';
$password = hash('sha256','xxxx');
$nonce    = base64_encode(rand(10000000000,99999999999));
date_default_timezone_set("America/Bogota");
$created  = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');


$header =  '<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
          <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>'.$username.'</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>'.$password.'</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis200401-wss-soap-message-security1.0#Base64Binary">'.$nonce.'</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>'.$created.'</wsu:Created>
          </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>';

$client->setHeaders($header);
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
$client->namespaces = array(
                    'soapenv'=>"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
                    'rep'=>"http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/ReportarFactura"
                  );

$date = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
$content = file_get_contents('ws_f0900467785000000000f.zip');
$base = base64_encode($content);

$body =  '<rep:EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion>
        <rep:NIT>900467785</rep:NIT>
        <rep:InvoiceNumber>990000001</rep:InvoiceNumber>
        <rep:IssueDate>'.$date.'</rep:IssueDate>
        <rep:Document>'.$base.'</rep:Document>
      </rep:EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion>';

$result = $client->call('EnvioFacturaElectronica',$body);

echo '<h2>Request</h2><pre>'. htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES) .'</pre>';
echo '<h2>Response</h2><pre>'. htmlspecialchars($client->response, ENT_QUOTES) .'</pre>';


?>
```

Estoy intentando usar un web service, enviando la siguiente petición:

```
POST /habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica HTTP/1.0
Host: facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co
User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 7017

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rep="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/ReportarFactura">
 <soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
   <wsse:UsernameToken>
    <wsse:Username>69d4f0b6-4924-4479-bdc6-26ef726eaee3</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password>6f9e2d69d7a806041b66c5af8c29b0d77c50ed02b17ae3b7002bb81f4c073e53</wsse:Password>
    <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis200401-wss-soap-message-security1.0#Base64Binary">MTI2NTU1ODAwMA==</wsse:Nonce>
    <wsu:Created>2017-08-17T14:24:14Z</wsu:Created>
   </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <rep:EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion>
   <rep:NIT>900467785</rep:NIT>
   <rep:InvoiceNumber>990000001</rep:InvoiceNumber>
   <rep:IssueDate>2017-08-17T14:24:14</rep:IssueDate>
   <rep:Document>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</rep:Document>
  </rep:EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Pero recibo la siguiente respuesta del web service:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 17 Aug 2017 19:24:07 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1079
Connection: close

<html>
 <head>
  <title>JBoss Web/7.4.8.Final-redhat-4 - JBWEB000064: Error report</title>
  <style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 400 - </h1>
  <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
  <p><b>JBWEB000309: type</b> JBWEB000067: Status report</p>
  <p><b>JBWEB000068: message</b> <u></u></p>
  <p><b>JBWEB000069: description</b> <u>JBWEB000120: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.</u></p>
  <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
  <h3>JBoss Web/7.4.8.Final-redhat-4</h3>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: EL Web Service de la DIAN es una porquería checa si se esta generando bien tu password y la fecha debe estar en el formato ISO 8601, por lo demás no veo fallo en tu petición, ¿te muestra algún otro error?

Comment: Hola pudieron resolver el error?? una pregunta al fin <wsse:Password> debe ir cual clave y una herramienta para parar a sha-256 a mi me sale que no me he autenticado

Answer (score 1):

tienes

```
$header =  '<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
```

pero esa url esta mal, yo tengo

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
```

el error está en 
oasis-200401wss-wssecurity